# Is this the correct way to write a MicroPython module that works across different builds?

Tags: python, module, micropython

I'm writing a module for an I2C temperature sensor (TMP117) with cross-compatability being a priority.

The MicroPython implementation is different on BBC Micro:bit and Raspberry Pi Pico - an important difference is how the I2C driver is implemented:

- Pico uses the [machine](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/machine.I2C.html) class to drive i2c: `i2c.writeto`
- Micro:bit has already defined `i2c.write` (bundled with `from microbit import *`) [docs](https://microbit-micropython.readthedocs.io/en/v1.0.1/i2c.html)

This simple difference in naming is really all that affects compatability!

So far I have shoehorned a working solution so my module `tmp117.py` is usable on both platforms.
In `tmp117.py`, when the sensor class is initialised it checks the `sysname` and declares function pointers `self.i2cWrite` and `self.i2cRead` that are assigned the hardware-appropriate definition.

However, I'm quite new to Python and imagine I may have committed many atrocities in doing so by eg. mishandling namespaces or chewing up memory with inappropriate imports. Can anybody comment if this method is appropriate? In terms of scalability, needless imports, namespaces etc.

**main.py**

```
# TMP117 minimal example code
from tmp117 import *
from time import sleep

mySensor = tmp117()

while True:
    # Read and print the temperature in various units
    tempC = mySensor.readTempC() # Celsius
    
    tempStringC = str(tempC) # convert temperature number to string
  
    print("it's " + tempStringC)
    
    sleep(1)
```

**tmp117.py**

```
# A simple class to read temperature from the TMP117 i2c temperature sensor
# Currently only supports reading temperature in C, F, K. Does not support
# alarms.

# This module has been tested with the following development boards:
#    • BBC Micro:bit
#    • Raspberry Pi Pico (RP2040)

import os


if os.uname().sysname == 'microbit':
    from microbit import *
else: # for Raspberry Pi Pico
    from machine import I2C
    i2c = I2C(0)
    
print("Running on " + os.uname().sysname)
    
# Register definitions
REG_TEMPC = b'\x00'

class tmp117(object):    
    def __init__(self, addr_=0x48, i2c_=i2c):
        if os.uname().sysname == 'microbit':
            self.i2c = i2c_
            self.addr = addr_
            self.i2cWrite = self.i2c.write
            self.i2cRead = self.i2c.read
        else:
            self.i2c = i2c_
            self.addr = addr_
            self.i2cWrite = self.i2c.writeto
            self.i2cRead = self.i2c.readfrom
    
    def readTempC(self):
        self.i2cWrite(self.addr, REG_TEMPC)
        data = self.i2cRead(self.addr, 2) # returns a bytes object
        tempDataRaw = int.from_bytes(data, 'big')
        # handle negatives (MicroPython int.from_bytes does not support signed conversion (yet)
        if tempDataRaw >= 0x8000:
            return -256.0 + (tempDataRaw - 0x8000) * 7.8125e-3 # One LSB equals 7.812 mdegC
        else:
            return tempDataRaw * 7.8125e-3 # One LSB equals 7.812 mdegC
```

Comment: I would only like to say that `import *` is generally considered bad practice. See the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#more-on-modules).

Comment: Thanks for your input! I'm going to comb through the tute again. In general, I agree. At least in the official examples, `from microbit import *` appears to be standard boilerplate for microbit projects. I suppose the intention is to reduce the amount of intimidating syntax required for beginners/students to get started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my choice of doing the same thing would be define `_PLATFORM` variable, set it accordingly and use it later:

```
import os

if os.uname().sysname == 'microbit':
    _PLATFORM = 'microbit'
elif os.uname().sysname == 'rpico':  # not sure about real value
    _PLATFORM = 'pico'
else:
    raise Exception('Unsupported platform')


if _PLATFORM == 'microbit':
    from microbit import *
elif _PLATFORM == 'pico': # for Raspberry Pi Pico
    from machine import I2C
    i2c = I2C(0)


print("Running on {}".format(_PLATFORM))    # <<--- use format() function to save RAM
    
# Register definitions
REG_TEMPC = b'\x00'

class tmp117(object):    
    def __init__(self, addr_=0x48, i2c_=i2c):
        if _PLATFORM == 'microbit':
            self.i2c = i2c_
            self.addr = addr_
            self.i2cWrite = self.i2c.write
            self.i2cRead = self.i2c.read
        elif _PLATFORM == 'pico':
            self.i2c = i2c_
            self.addr = addr_
            self.i2cWrite = self.i2c.writeto
            self.i2cRead = self.i2c.readfrom
    
    def readTempC(self):
        self.i2cWrite(self.addr, REG_TEMPC)
        data = self.i2cRead(self.addr, 2) # returns a bytes object
        tempDataRaw = int.from_bytes(data, 'big')
        # handle negatives (MicroPython int.from_bytes does not support signed conversion (yet)
        if tempDataRaw >= 0x8000:
            return -256.0 + (tempDataRaw - 0x8000) * 7.8125e-3 # One LSB equals 7.812 mdegC
        else:
            return tempDataRaw * 7.8125e-3 # One LSB equals 7.812 mdegC
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for your input. From your answer I'm inferring:
a) It's cheaper to just make the `_Platform` variable rather than inoke `...sysname()` repeatedly
b) There's nothing else *glaringly* wrong

For extensibility, I'm only defining the 'edge cases' where a uPython implementation deviates from using vanilla `machine`. Since Pico uses `machine`, I didn't explicitly check for it.